# MVC form load calling both controller method and its overload method instead of calling on click methos ? Code attached

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

i am saving data on click button but view when load first time entering to overload method ?

my view code is like,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageQuestion", "Questions", FormMethod.Post))
{
 <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
}
```

and my Controller is like,

```
public ActionResult ManageQuestion()
{
    //List<SelectListItem> QuestionType = Survey();
        //return View(QuestionType);
        return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ManageQuestion(Question Objquest)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SurveyAppEntities ObjEntity = new SurveyAppEntities();
        string strDDLValue = Request.Form["DDlDemo"].ToString();
        Objquest.QuestionType = strDDLValue;
        ObjEntity.Questions.Add(Objquest);
        ObjEntity.SaveChanges();
        ViewData["error"] = "Question Saved successfully";
        if (Objquest.ID > 0)
        {
        //    ViewBag.Success = "Inserted";

        }
        ModelState.Clear();
    }

    return View();
}
```

}

I am thinking that it must call overload ManageQuestion method on button click but when view load first time it is entering in overload methos resulting in error.

I got one example from net having same scenario but overload method is not calling there on first form load ?

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Mark the other method with [HttpGet]

Comment: i will make another method but how would i return same view from that new method ?

Comment: don't make another method, i mean mark the existing method with the attribute [HttpGet] so you will have two methods named "ManageQuestion" one will be used to render the view initially and the other to post the data and then rerender the view

Comment: Yes you are right but some how i am getting after changing it to httpGet i am getting null reference exception on this line "string strDDLValue = Request.Form["DDlDemo"].ToString();"

Comment: i tried this code and it is not having issue which i mentioned in my post "https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-data-using-Entity-Framework-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx"

Comment: @john but code snippet of View which you have added it just has button only on it.  then how you will find Dropdown value. Are you new to ASP.NET stack?